# Read file from "dir B" if it doesn't exists in "dir A"

Tags: apache-2.2

We've got multiple sites that are pointing to the same directory. This is because they are basically the same site, the only differce is, the language. Now we've got a plan to change the design for only one of these sites. We want to keep the complete structure of the site, so moving is no option. But we want only a couple of files different from the other sites. I want to create the following situation in apache:

Two directories:

- /website/dir_A
- /website/dir_B

When let's say an image is called: http://website/img/logo.png
It has to give logo.png back that is part of dir_A. If dir_A doesn't contain logo.png, it has to give logo.png back that is part of dir_B.

I had hoped "Alias" could do this, but couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with mod_rewrite. I think doing something like this should work:

```
DocumentRoot /website/dir_A
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/dir_B/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You might consider putting all of the rewrite-related directives in a <Location> block so as to specify that the rewrites would only apply to the directory that could contain files he wants to serve.

Comment: how do you mean with location? And the rule should point to the directory within the documentRoot set within Virtualhost?
     <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com

     DocumentRoot /home/abc/example.com/htdocs


  <location /img>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/bbb/img/$1 [L]

  </location>

</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this via Apache directly, but if you are running on a dedicated server of VPS (rather than shared hosting) running Linux you could use [a union filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) to achieve this.